# How to create a vertical line intensity profile (line projection) by coding?

Tags: image-processing, dm-script

How does one create a vertical line intensity profile (line projection) by coding?

The code shown below generates a horizontal line intensity profile from an image.

Is there any code to get a vertical line intensity profile? 
(Or should we rotate the image first, then do the horizontal one?)

And, I know that the “half Minor” is length of the line that generates the intensity profile, but I do not know what is the meaning of “1”?

And, there is no number or character respects the width of the line?

In addition, the line intensity profile that generated by the below code cannot show as “home display”, the start point of Y coordinate is not 0,what is the reason ?

```
line_projection := CreateFloatImage ( "line projection", halfMinor, 1 )
line_projection = 0
line_projection[icol,0] += imgFlat
line_projection /= samples
```

Comment: Hi, please - when possible - try to limit the questions to one *specific* (coding) question. This helps the Q&A format of this site. Ideally "short question = short answer" with good tagging helps other users to find answers when they are searching.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will remember and pay attention with my future post. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### General hint:

> When you are unsure about the meaning of parameters in a command, try typing the command in a separate script but with *incorrect* parameters. You get an error, but the results-window gives you the full signature with often more meaningful parameter names.

If you do this with `CreateFloatImage` you will get:

> `RealImage createfloatimage( String title, RealNumber width, RealNumber height )`

As you can see, the second parameter specifies the height of a two-dimensional image, so your script code creates a 2D image of size [halfMinor x 1].

### Projecting:

The following script produces the projected intensities (mean value) both vertically and horizontally:

```
image front := GetFrontImage()
number sx,sy
front.GetSize(sx,sy)

image vProj := RealImage( "Vertical", 4, sx )
vProj[icol,0] += front
vProj *= 1/sy
vProj.ShowImage()

image hProj := RealImage( "Horizontal", 4, sy )
hProj[irow,0] += front
hProj *= 1/sx
hProj.ShowImage()
```